# 2010 Macbook Pro keeps crashing in Adobe - does it need more video memory?

Tags: macbook-pro, video, memory, adobe

We have a late 2010 Macbook Pro 15, 8gb memory, 512mb video. When we have more than one Adobe product open (And sometimes only one product) the computer will freeze. Our designer who uses the computer is blaming it on the lack of video memory.

Do I need to order a Mac with at least 1gb of video memory to run the new Adobe products or is it more a function of RAM?

We are using Adobe suite cs6 (Photoshop says version 13)

Photoshop
InDesign
Illustrator

Comment: Please edit your answer to be more specific about which apps and version of Adobe you are working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be pure out of memory, but it may be that both products are fighting over the OpenGL implementation that Adobe uses.

Try this - it may need some fiddling to get the best balance
[this is for Photoshop, idk the precise locations for other Adobe apps]

In Prefs > Performance, reduce the overall memory requirement - it ought to handle this OK by itself, running into pagefile if needed, but just to see how it goes with this reduced…

Either disable "Use Graphics Processor" or open Advanced Settings… & selectively disable sections until you find which is causing the issue.

[image]

If you decide to leave "Use Graphics Processor" on, then look in Prefs > 3D & drop the memory requirement in there to half your card's total memory, less a little for the system.

All these tweaks will require you to relaunch each app, so it may take some time to finally settle at something that works best for you.

The alternative, as you first surmised, would be to get a more powerful graphics card with greater memory - if that would be even possible on a Macbook, which I somehow doubt.

[Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.8-aluminum-15-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html) states [for the high-end i7 machine]:

> NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M with 512 MB of dedicated GDDR3 memory and Intel HD Graphics with 256 MB of RAM shared with the system -- that Mac OS X automatically switches between for better graphics performance and better battery life, respectively, depending on application use.

One thing you should definitely check is that it is at least switching over to the NVidia rather than using the Intel card.
[gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io) would be the go-to tool for that kind of task.

Answer (score 1):

The 2010 MacBook Pros are known to have issues with the NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M graphics card. Apple was issuing replacements to the graphics cards on that model, but that period has expired. Take a look at [this link](http://www.macworld.com/article/2062783/cures-for-a-panicking-mid-2010-macbook-pro.html) for more information.

The NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M is built onto the motherboard. It is not possible to repair without replacing the entire motherboard.

Sorry there's no other option. If you feel confidant enough to pull off a motherboard swap, you might be able to find one parted out of a scrapped Macbook Pro.